# Using LINQ, can I give the "grouping" a name in VB.NET like I can in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

My goal is to group and transform data, but have both the transformed and un-transformed "grouped data" available.

Consider the following minimal C# example:

```
var data = new[] { ("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 1) };

var groupedAndTransformed =
    from d in data
    group d by d.Item1 into g
    select new
    {
        Untransformed = g,
        Transformed = g.Key + string.Join(",", g.Select(tuple => tuple.Item2))
    };
```

Now I try to do the same in VB.NET, but I can only achieve that with a two-step process, because VB.NET's `Group By` works somewhat differently than C#'s `group by`:

```
Dim data = {("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 1)}

Dim step1 =
    From d In data
    Group d By d.Item1 Into Group

Dim groupedAndTransformed =
    From g In step1
    Select
        Untransformed = g,
        Transformed = g.Item1 + String.Join(",", g.Group.Select(Function(tuple) tuple.Item2))
```

The problem seems to be that VB.NET's `Group By` puts the result of the grouping into some kind of "global namespace": If I continue writing LINQ code directly after `Group d By d.Item1 Into Group`, I have both `Item1` and `Group` in scope. However, I don't have a name for the `IGrouping` consisting of them (dubbed `g` in C#), so I need the second step.

**Can I somehow tell VB's `Group By` statement to give me a name for the `IGrouping`?** The only other workarounds I found were to use (a) functional syntax instead of declarative LINQ syntax (i.e., call `Enumerable.GroupBy` directly) or (b) nest step1 into the second step (i.e., `From g In (...step1...)`). Is there something I have missed?

Answer (score 1):

It's too bad that the C# and VB LINQ syntax is so incompatible.
I think the following VB LINQ is as close as you can get the to the original (with Option Infer On of course):

```
Dim data = { ("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 1) }

Dim groupedAndTransformed = From d In data
    Group d By d.Item1 Into g = Group
    Select New With {
        Key .Untransformed = g,
        Key .Transformed = Item1 & String.Join(",", g.Select(Function(tuple) tuple.Item2))
    }
```

I've tested and it compiles and runs but it's hard to tell if it will function identically.

Comment: Close, but this loses the group key information. In C# `g` is an `IGrouping<string, (string, int)>`, whereas in VB it's just the latter part (an `IEnumerable<(string, int)>`). Admittedly, it does not make much difference in the toy example (because the key can easily be reconstructed with `g.First().Item1`), but it makes a difference if the grouping key is a non-trivial operation on the data row.

Comment: @Heinzi: Yes, I saw that in the debugger when comparing both.

Answer (score 1):

What Dave said, but I just wanted to note that overall it might be neater to use method syntax:

```vb
    Dim groupedAndTransformed = data.GroupBy(
        Function(d) d.Item1,
        Function(k, g) New With {
            Key .Untransformed = g
            Key .Transformed = g.Select(Function(tuple) tuple.Item2)
        }
    )
```

Or if you want to dump the Untransformed, there's an overload that will help reduce the subselect

```vb
    Dim groupedAndTransformed = data.GroupBy(
        Function(d) d.Item1,
        Function(d) d.Item2,
        Function(k, g) New With {
            Key .Transformed = k & String.Join(",", g)
        }
    )
```

I do wish they'd shorten `Function` to `F`

Answer (score 1):

In the posted C# code, the variable `g` is of type System.Linq.Lookup.Grouping.  This type is an internal class of the [System.Linq.Lookup type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2?view=net-6.0).  Since the intent of the LINQ appears to be to extract the Lookup groupings, perhaps it would be better to write the query to use the [Enumerable.ToLookup Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?view=net-6.0) to create an enumerable of the groupings.

```
var groupedAndTransformed = from grp in data.ToLookup((item) => item.Item1)
                            select new
                            {
                              Untransformed = grp,
                              Transformed = grp.Key + string.Join(",", grp.Select((tuple) => tuple.Item2))
                            };
```

This can be directly translated to VB code.

```
Dim groupedAndTransformed = From grp In data.ToLookup(Function(item) item.Item1)
                            Select New With
                             {
                               Key .Untransformed = grp,
                               Key .Transformed = grp.Key & String.Join(",", grp.Select(Function(tuple) tuple.Item2))
                             }
```

I realize this does not answer the question of how to force VB's "Group By" to use the same internal implementation as the C# compiler emits, but do you really want code that relies upon an implementation detail?

Comment: Ohhh... that's brilliant! I knew about `group by` and I knew about `ToLookup`, but I never saw the similarity between them. So obvious in hindsight! Thanks for adding another tool to my LINQ tool belt.